# Attempting to create a binary search in python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a binary search, but am unable to get the code to work for numbers 4, 6, 7, 8 and 9. Does anyone have any ideas why?

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

search = 3
first = 0
last = (len(list)-1)
found = False

while first <= last and not found:
    mid = (first+last//2)
    if list[mid] == search:
        found = True
   else:
    if search > list[mid]:
        for i in range(mid):
            list.remove(list[0])
        print(list)
    else:
        for i in range(mid):
            last = (len(list)-1)
            list.remove(list[last])
        print(list)

if found == True:
    print("Item found")
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: that's a binary search btw

Comment: `(first+last//2)` sticks out as a mistake right away. Know anything about operator precedence? Simply inspecting the values of `first`, `last`, and `mid` in each iteration of the loop would probably tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in itself is very bad, you are deleting the elements of the original list, which is unnecessary and also wastes time. Also, the list is unusable for further searches.

Try this :

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
search = 3
first = 0
last = (len(list)-1)
found=False
while first <= last:
    mid = first + (last-first)/2
    if list[mid] == search:
        found=True
        break
    else:
        if search > list[mid]:
                first=mid+1
                print list[first:last+1]
        else:
                last=mid-1
                print list[first:last+1]
if found == True:
    print "Element Found"
else:
    print "Element not found"
```

Cleaner way, no need to remove any elements.

Comment: @Dean might want to see the list after each iteration, this code defeats his purpose.

Comment: @Nazmul when assigning values to first and last, he could still see the list by printing lists[first:mid-1] or lists[mid+1:last] depending on condition

Comment: added print statements for the same